# How to put a command in nohup in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, nohup

I am trying to put `shred` command in `nohup` for shell script, once the script is run it has to take input and run shred operation on a device in `nohup` mode. The problem is when I add `nohup` to command the script does not exit and run the command in background, also i am trying to send success and failure mails with the output once shred operation is completed.
What I tried so far:

```
nohup shred -n 2 "device name" > success.out 2>failure.out
if [$? -eq 0]
then 
    mail -s "success" -a success.out "EmailID" <.
    exit 0
else 
    mail -s "failure" -a failure.out "EmailID" <.
    exit 1
fi
```

I am getting the success email with attachment n=but the attachment is non readable format, is there any other way??

Comment: Why don't you just `nohup` the script itself?

Comment: Also, `[$? -eq 0]` will always fail -- `[0` isn't a command, and neither is `[1`. You need to use spaces: `[` is the name of a command, so you can't run `[$?` any more than you can run `ls~`. Similarly, `]` needs to be the last argument to the `[` command; it can't be smooshed onto another string.

Answer (score -1):

"*the script does not exit and run the command in background*".

You do not tell the script to background it.  Add &.

So:

```
nohup shred -n 2 "device name" & >success.out 2>failure.out
```

Will do it.

Comment: The `$?` test still won't be able to see whether `shred` succeeded.